# How to Script YOLO Detection From Python to Reactive LEDs on Arduino Broad

Tags: python, arduino-uno, yolo, yolov8

I have my own pre-trained YOLO model, and I want to have different colors of LEDs light up on Arduino Uno breadbroad when different labels are being detected from my webcam.

So, I was thinking of first assigning the command for different LEDs to light up. ("G" for green led, "R" for red led, "Y" for yellow led, "A" for turning both red and yellow led at the same time, and "0" to turn off all led.
)
I started with my Arduino code as below:

```c
char command;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);  // Green LED pin
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);  // Red LED pin
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);  // Yellow LED pin
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        command = Serial.read();
        if (command == 'G') {
            // Turn on green LED
            digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(3, LOW);  // Turn off red LED
            digitalWrite(4, LOW);  // Turn off yellow LED
        } else if (command == 'R') {
            // Turn on red LED
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // Turn off green LED
            digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(4, LOW);   // Turn off yellow LED
        } else if (command == 'Y') {
            // Turn on yellow LED
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // Turn off green LED
            digitalWrite(3, LOW);   // Turn off red LED
            digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        } else if (command == 'A') {
            // Turn on both red and yellow LEDs
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // Turn off green LED
            digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        } else if (command == '0') {
            // Turn off all LEDs
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(3, LOW);
            digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

In my YOLO model, there are three classes

```
#Classes
names:
  0: aaa
  1: bbb
  2: ccc
```

Therefore, for my python code I started with first turning on the webcam and loading then using serial library to connect to arduino.

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
import serial
import time
import sys

# Load my YOLO model using
model = YOLO("best.pt")

# Open the serial port for communication with Arduino
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)  # Change 'COM3' to your Arduino port
```

after that, I want to assign the labels with command to Arduino, and I also try to do a little

```py
# Map the class labels to corresponding Arduino commands
label_commands = {
    'aaa': 'G',
    'bbb': 'R',
    'ccc': 'Y',
    'aaa_bbb': 'A',
    'aaa_bbb_ccc': 'A',
    'none': '0'
}

while True:
    try:
        results = model.predict(source="0", show=True)  # assumes '0' is your source identifier

        # Extract the detected labels from results
        detected_labels = [item['label'] for item in results.xyxy[0].numpy()]

        # Determine the Arduino command based on detected labels
        if 'aaa' in detected_labels and 'bbb' in detected_labels and 'ccc' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['aaa_bbb_ccc']
        elif 'aaa' in detected_labels and 'bbb' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['aaa_bbb']
        elif 'aaa' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['aaa']
        elif 'bbb' in detected_labels and 'ccc' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['aaa_bbb_ccc']
        elif 'bbb' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['bbb']
        elif 'ccc' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['ccc']
        else:
            command = label_commands['none']

        # Print the command for debugging
        print(f"Sending command to Arduino: {command}")
        sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush the standard output

        # Send the command to Arduino
        arduino.write(command.encode())

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush the standard output

    # Wait for 5 seconds before sending the next command
    time.sleep(5)
```

BUT, this part of code doesn't work at all. I know my arduino is connected for sure, and I have also tested with from randoming sending the letter command to arduino from python, which worked perfectly.

Also when I run this code, the run window are showing only things like:

```
1/1: 0... Success ✅ (inf frames of shape 640x480 at 25.00 FPS)


WARNING ⚠️ inference results will accumulate in RAM unless `stream=True` is passed, causing potential out-of-memory
errors for large sources or long-running streams and videos. See https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/ for help.

Example:
    results = model(source=..., stream=True)  # generator of Results objects
    for r in results:
        boxes = r.boxes  # Boxes object for bbox outputs
        masks = r.masks  # Masks object for segment masks outputs
        probs = r.probs  # Class probabilities for classification outputs

0: 480x640 (no detections), 141.0ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 182.2ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 134.3ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 122.1ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 121.4ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 147.5ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 131.5ms
0: 480x640 (no detections), 140.3ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 127.1ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 124.1ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 123.2ms
0: 480x640 1 aaa, 172.2ms
...
```

even with my debugging script, it doesn't tell me what command is being sent to the arduino broad

```py
        # Print the command for debugging
        print(f"Sending command to Arduino: {command}")
        sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush the standard output
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the YOLO part, this can be helpful: first, as you predict a live stream, use `stream=True` to get a results generator. Next, to reach the class names of the detected objects, you first need to get their class ids and then refer to the `result.names` which is a list of model names, in your case it will be ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']. Example for a COCO pre-trained YOLO model:

```
model = YOLO(yolov8n.pt)
results = model.predict(source="0", stream=True)
# for each frame
for result in results:
  class_ids = result.boxes.cls.tolist()
  detected_labels = [result.names[int(i)] for i in class_ids]
  #print(detected_labels)
  #['person', 'person', 'cat']
  #(if 2 person, 1 cat detected in a frame)
```

More about how to use [results generator](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#key-features-of-predict-mode) and how to work with the prediction [results](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#working-with-results).

Answer (score 1):

These could be potential issues:

1. How the labels are being extracted from the YOLO model's output - in case the labels aren't extracted correctly, commands are not going to be sent to Arduino.
2. Even though the Arduino is connected and it's (as you stated) working with random commands, it might have problems with the communication when it's done in the loop with the YOLO detections.

And then, when it comes to not seeing the debugging output, the program itself maybe isn't reaching that part of the code, or maybe there could be with the way is being handled.

So, to approach this, you'd need to make sure that labels are correctly extracted, you might want to print these labels right after extraction to see if they're what you expect. I'd also simplify code to send fixed command to the Arduino in each loop iteration, regardless of the YOLO output, that way you'd confirm that the basic loop and serial communication is working correctly. Another thing, Arduino sometimes takes a bit of time to start up and establish serial communication, so you might want to adjust Python script to wait for the Arduino to be read, also I'd check for exceptions which are more detailed to see where exactly your code might be failing, it'd be pinpoint to the step of the code where the issue is.

So, here's code that might be helpful in order for you to be able to provide us to help you or you might even be able to understand where's the problem and solve it:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import serial
import time
import sys

# Load YOLO model
model = YOLO("best.pt")

# Open serial port for Arduino
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
time.sleep(2)  # Wait for Arduino to initialize

# Label commands mapping
label_commands = {
    'aaa': 'G', 'bbb': 'R', 'ccc': 'Y', 'aaa_bbb': 'A', 'aaa_bbb_ccc': 'A', 'none': '0'
}

while True:
    try:
        # Get YOLO predictions
        results = model.predict(source="0")
        detected_labels = [item['label'] for item in results.xyxy[0].numpy()]

        # Determine command
        command = '0'  # Default command
        if 'aaa' in detected_labels:
            command = label_commands['aaa']
        # Add other conditions as required

        # Debugging output
        print(f"Detected Labels: {detected_labels}")
        print(f"Sending command to Arduino: {command}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # Send command to Arduino
        arduino.write(command.encode())

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(5)  # Wait before next iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

SO updates and now it's finally working thanks to the answer by hanna_liavoshka.

```
for result in results:
  class_ids = result.boxes.cls.tolist()
  detected_labels = [result.names[int(i)] for i in class_ids]
  print("Detected:", detected_labels)
  #['aaa', 'aaa', 'ccc']
  #(if 2 aaa, 1 ccc detected in a frame)
  label_commands = {
      'aaa': 'G', 'bbb': 'R', 'ccc': 'Y', 'none': '0'
  }

  if 'aaa' in detected_labels and not 'bbb' in detected_labels and not 'ccc' in detected_labels:
    command = label_commands['aaa']

  #... and the rest of the elifs 
  else:
    command = label_commands['none']

  print(f"Detected Labels: {detected_labels}")
  print(f"Sending command to Arduino: {command}")

  arduino.write(command.encode())
```

Putting the answer here just in case anyone might encounter the same problem in the future